# Best way to put 20 elements in a coordinate system with neighbouring elements unique

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx

This question is regarding libGDX, but I think it's in fact more Java/algorithm related.

Part of my game includes placing 20 elements out of predefined 30 elements list on a screen (so effectively a coordinate system) in 20 partially-predefined places.
By partially predefined I mean that they are predefined for each screen, but there can be dozens of screens, so they can be as well treated as random.
The elements will be selected randomly, but the elements close to each other must be unique. By close I mean in range of some arbitrary defined distance X. Effectively each place will have around 3 'close neightbours'.

The best way I can think of so far is as follows:

1. Calculate the distance between all places. If a given distance between A and B is lower than X put two entries in a map - one (A,B) and one (B,A)
2. Now start filling the places with elements
3. For each place create a list with all neightbours using the map from point 1 (let's call it N-list)
4. For each place create a temporary list with all possible (30) elements (let's call it E-list)
5. Get a random element from E-list
6. Iterate through N-list. For each place from the list get an element currently there (if there's any). For this a (place, element) map is needed, so it will be filled as the algorithm progresses.
7. If the found element is equal to the current random element remove this element from E-list and this place from N-list and come back to point 5
8. Proceed until all places are filled

Step 1 is in fact a separate algorithm, that probably can be tweaked, ex. if we calculated the A->B distance we don't need to calculate B->A, but that needs an additional map to store calculation info, etc.

I would like to know what you think of this way and if you have any ideas for a better one.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

P.S. Perhaps the terms I used could be better chosen, but I'm not a native speaker and I don't know English math terms :-)

Comment: Calculating the points lower than a certain threshold can be done more efficiently (in practice) using a sweep-line algorithm, although for 20, it's perhaps not worth the implementation cost.

Comment: all 30 elements are unique?

Comment: Yes, all 30 are unique.

Comment: Well if there are 30 elements and only 20 places, you can just use any 20 elements for filling these 20 places without repeating. Or is it not allowed and elements must repeat somewhere? I actually did my solution, I'll write it in the aswer since the comment length is too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understood your solution and this is what I thought of initially. But I think it can be slightly optimized by eliminating extra pairs and maps (or maybe not :)

First, create a map of locations where key is location position (or the location itself) and value is a list of location's parents who fall within the close range. Yes it will have multiple parents, not children, it is actually the same but parents are more fitting here as we'll see.

```
ArrayList<Place> place_list; // your list of places here
ArrayList<Element> element_list; // your list of elements here
HashMap<Place,ArrayList<Place>> parent_map = new HashMap<Place,ArrayList<Place>>;
ArrayList<Place> a;

for (int i = 0; i < place_list.size() - 1; i++) {
    Place place1 = place_list.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < place_list.size(); j++) {
        Place place2 = place_list.get(j);
        int dist = getDistance(place1, place2);
        if (dist > DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) continue;
        // if this place is within range,
        // add parent place to its list and put/update it to the map
        a = parent_map.get(place2);
        if (a == null) a = new ArrayList<Place>();
        a.add(place1);
        parent_map.put(place2, a);
    }
}
```

Now we have a map of all places that have parents. Next we do the following: if place does not have parents, it can choose any random element freely. If it does have parents, it checks what elements parents own and reduces the available set of elements. After the set was reduced, any random element can be chosen from it.

```
HashMap<Place,Element> used_place_map = new HashMap<Place,Element>(); // key is place, value is assigned element
ArrayList<Element> tmp_element_list;

for (i = 0; i < place_list.size(); i++) {
    Place place = place_list.get(i);
    a = parent_map.get(place);
    if (a == null) { // this place has no parents, use elements freely
        tmp_element_list = element_list;
    } else { // if it has parents, they have already registered their elements in used_place_map
        tmp_element_list = new ArrayList<Element>();
        // create list of available elements, lame
        for (j = 0; j < element_list.size(); j++) tmp_element_list.add(element_list.get(j));
        // now reduce it, very lame, sorry
        for (Place pl : a) {
            Element used_element = used_place_map.get(pl);
            for (j = 0; j < tmp_element_list.size(); j++) {
                if (used_element.equals(tmp_element_list.get(j)) {
                    tmp_element_list.remove(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // finally, get the random index on (probably reduced) array
    int element_id = Random.nextInt(tmp_element_list.size());
    Element element = element_list.get(element_id);
    // store our choice as future parent
    used_place_map.put(place, element);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking an effort to write the code. It seems to me that your algorithm is very similar to mine in terms of general approach, the difference is just a different order of steps. Because of that I think I will stick to mine. However I really liked your comment about using 20 unique elements for filling the places without repeating. It's true that simplest solutions are the hardest to find. I will upvote your comment when I have enough reputation :-) That said I'll probably have to use a smaller list of unique elements (10 or less), so I won't be able to use this solution in the end :-)

Comment: Yes it is very similar, but notice that you want to calculate distance between all places (like A-B and B-A) so you get more entries to check. By ordering them in a parent-child relation, I ensure only one pair will be created and parents will always define their elements first.

Comment: Good point. That actually can be used to tweak my point 1 algorithm. I will surely benefit from your answer, so thanks again.